# Find array index in JComboBox

Tags: arrays, jcombobox, getselection

I've some problems with this code:

```
String[] val = {"Smycke", "Aktie", "Apparat"};
    JComboBox<String> valboxen = new JComboBox<String>(val);

class NyLyss implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ave) {
            int valt = (int)valboxen.getSelectedIndex();

            if(valt == 0){

            SmyckesFormular smycke = new SmyckesFormular();

            int svar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Inlupp1.this, smycke);
            if (svar != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                return;
            String namnet = smycke.getNamn();
            int stenar = smycke.getStenar();
            boolean guld = smycke.getGuld();
            Smycken smy = new Smycken(namnet, stenar, guld);
            alla.add(smy);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is just a little part of all code in the program.

I want the "smyckesformular" to open in a new window, but i don't get it to work.
I don't know if it is the getSelectedIndex that's wrong or if it's the code beneath?

Comment: any error/exception you see?

Comment: No, i don't get any errors...
Edit. When i compile the program i get this error: "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.awt.AWTError: BoxLayout can't be shared"

Comment: That's at runtime? Where have you used layout manager? Which line its pointing to?

Comment: Is SmyckesFormular a JFrame class? Or is your JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog() not opening?

Comment: This is how my layout manager looks like: 
SmyckesFormulär(){
  super("Nytt smycke");
  
  setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
  
  JPanel först = new JPanel();
  add(först);
  först.add(new JLabel("Namn:"));
  först.add(namnFält);
  
  JPanel andra = new JPanel();
  add(andra);
  andra.add(new JLabel("Stenar:"));
  add(stenFält);
  
  JPanel tredje = new JPanel();
   add(tredje);
   avGuld = new JCheckBox("Av Guld");
   tredje.add(avGuld);
 }
The exception points to:
"at SmyckesFormulär.<init>(SmyckesFormulär.java:13)
at Inlupp1$NyLyss.actionPerformed(Inlupp1.java:73)"

Comment: Yes Shar1er80, smyckesFormular is a JFrame class. The JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog() won't open...

Comment: Post your SmyckesFormular class in your question. It's a little difficult to read it in the comments.